# Do I need a plywood base to install granite countertops?

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-counters, countertops

I will have the following run of cabinets (which will be screwed together and to the back wall) and will install a 20mm (3/4") thick granite countertop over it (with sink and cooktop range).

[image: base cabinets]

I've seem people saying that a plywood backer is important, and some other people saying that it is more trouble than it is worth and the cabinets provide enought support as it its. The maximum space between to cabinet walls is about 90cm (3 ft).

Comment: There was good discussion on this topic on this thread yesterday: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107687/will-a-1-thick-granite-countertop-span-22-inches -- though like you mentioned, people seem to be of both opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this seems pretty clear when you consider one thing: It takes a substantial amount of force to bend granite, *but it only needs to move a few micrometers* to break*.

Now you just ask yourself whether a layer of plywood will prevent that miniscule movement. *No, it won't.* Physics has no interest in the opinion of the masses.

So, you might use a plywood substrate to help replicate a thicker top, or to reinforce poorly-built cabinets, or to help maintain position by adhering the stone to it, or for other practical reasons, but you don't do it to *support, stiffen, or strengthen* the stone. That would take something much more substantial and rigid, such as the vertical hardwood cabinet rails that typically exist at the front and rear of a cabinet.

<sub>** Or a few dozen, or a few hundred. The result is the same.*</sub>

Comment: What are the hardwood cabinet rails you mentioned? The faceframe?

Comment: Yes. Vertical 1x3 or so.

Comment: Hum? I'm not following. Do you have a link for a cabinet carcass that has the rail you are talking about?

Comment: Almost *any* cabinet has a rail above the door or drawer. I'm not sure where the confusion lies.

Comment: But in all plywood carcasses those are also plywood usually. My confusion was the due to "vertical hardwood" rails. Those are horizontal and not always hardwood. :)
In my drawing you can see the rails, but the are horizontal and plywood like the rest of the carcass.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking of that type of cabinet. My experience is almost exclusive to custom cabinetry with [full overlay faceframes](http://www.barkerdoor.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/cabinet%20with%20face%20fram%20only%20in%20paint%20grade.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to glue on stone worktops.

If you don't have a plywood backer (Or MDF etc) then the stone worktop is directly glued onto the cabinets and it is very hard to remove cabinets if you ever need to.

The other practical issue is it is normal to order the stone worktop once the cabinets are installed so a template can be made for cutting the stone.   The plywood backer allows the kitchen to be used before the stone worktop arrives.

Comment: Mine ( 36" X  68") is not glued and has just sat there for 25 years ; I planned to glue it but never got around to it. It is one inch thick so thinner than most, no backer , just the standard cabinet framework.